# Combine and store multiple SQL columns into a single column programmatically

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I have multiple columns in an Access DB, I want to combine the fields A, B, C and store them in column D with a comma separator between them.  D = A,B,C.

Right now I am using a OleDbConnection, but I'm open to other methods.  How can I combine and store the row data from multiple SQL columns into a single column?

Comment: What is the data type of A, B, and C.  Also, does column D already exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the simple case of strings, you can use an update statement:

```
Update table set D=A+','+B+','+C
```

This may not be a good idea however.  You may want to extrapolate on "Why" you want to do this, as there may be a better option.

Comment: It's a bit tricky why I wanted to do it, its basically because of a limitation with ESRI locator styles. I'm pretty sure this is TMI, but this expands the context somewhat, http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5786/why-doesnt-us-one-address-locator-style-have-city-state-or-zip-code-fields

Comment: I think in this situation you've be better off using @HansUp's solution to calculate the field when you need it.  If you want to access it as a column, create a view into your table that includes the calculated column.  If you create a new column and populate it with calculated data; then you open yourself up to stale data when other columns are updated.  This is "a bad thing" in database design.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO table (d) VALUES (SELECT a + "," + b + "," + c FROM table)
```

Many assumtions are made above.

Comment: I get the impression he wants them lined up with existing rows. I don't think this method will work for that...

Answer (score 2):

I question why you want to store those A, B, and C values redundantly in another column D.  D could be a field expression which concatenates the other field values as needed.

```
SELECT A & "," & B & "," & C AS D
FROM YourTable;
```

If you use your original approach (storing the concatenated values in a separate column, D), you would need to ensure D gets updated every time values change in A, B, and/or C.  With the SELECT query approach, D is always guaranteed to accurately reflect the current values in A, B, and C ... for no additional effort.

Comment: +1 sage advice.  Creating a database that can be "corrupted" so easily is rarely the correct answer to the problem.